# Point a Jenkins job to only run a branch?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, github

**Problem**

I have a selenium suite that takes over 4 hours to run. I'm trying to cut down that time in simple way.

**My approach:**

1) I created 3 branches, each branch has a different testng.xml file; by different, I mean that every testng.xml file runs a different set of tests.

2) I created 3 Jenkins jobs, each job should run the testng.xml file from one of the 3 branches.

Problem:
Every time I try to run my build, it seems that the testng.xml file in my master branch gets built.

**Things I tried:**

1) I tried specifying the name of my branch in the Branches to build's "Branch Specifier", but that didn't work.

2) I also tried adding the entire path of my branch as the "Repository URL" (eg. https://github.com/myProject/tree/branchTwo), but I get a status code 128 back

**Goal:**

I'm wondering if there's some configuration my Jenkins jobs to run each of the three jobs manually?

Comment: In branch specifier `remotes\origin\branchName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add branch name and Run
[image]

ADD repository URL and Branch name on a branch to build the field. If your project is maven project you can run any class using shell command.

Example:

```
sudo mvn exec:java -D exec.mainClass=owasp.SiteVisit
```

Answer (score 0):

adding a remotes/origin/branchName did it. Thanks @ Joao Vitorino